# How to count total number in HTML Table

Tags: javascript, php, html, arrays

I have simple html table with value of 1 and 0. I want to count total number of 1's in single row. How can I count with using PHP. I search every method but all methods linked with database.
I tried count function but its not working.I don't know which PHP function is better to use below is my code and html table values.

Below is my table values

```
Number   Value  
   1    0
   0    0
   0    1
   1    1
   1    0
<?php 
 echo "Total number of 1's are".count(value == 1);
?>
```

I am not using any database. The full code is below:

```
<table width="600" border="1" align="center" cellspacing="5" bgcolor="#F0F0F0">
    <tr>
        <th>Number</th>
        <th>Value</th>
        <th>Find 1's</th>
    </tr> 
    <?php
        if(isset($_POST['submit']))
        {
            $x = $_POST['firstint'];
            $y = $_POST['secondint'];

            Count($x,$y);
        }

        function Count($x,$y)
        {
            for($i=$x; $i<=$y; $i++)
            {
                $value = $i/strlen($i);

                ?> 
                <tr>
                    <td width="68" align="center"><?php echo $i; ?></td>
                    <td width="68" align="center"><?php echo $value; ?></td>
                    <td width="68" align="center">
                    <?php 
                        if($value == 1)
                        { 
                            echo "One" ; 
                        }
                        else
                        { 
                            echo "Zero"; 
                        }
                    ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <?php
            }
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="center"></td>
            <td align="left"><b>Total Count:</b></td>
            <td align="left"><b>
            <?php
                echo count($value == 1);
            ?>
            </b></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
        }
    ?>  
</table>
```

Comment: Are you using a database table or HTML table?

Comment: Where does javascript come into this? Are you wanting a javascript solution or did you just tag it because it was suggested?

Comment: HTML table without any database

Comment: it's will easier with javascript or Jquery.

In php, better you do a forloop to create this table. then you count it in your loop

Comment: You need to show us more of your code. At the moment it's not clear where this table comes from or what it looks like.

Comment: How was your html table generated? Did you just create a table with html tags? like `<table><tr><td>....</td></tr></table>` or did you use php to generate the table?

Comment: that's all jose more code is just html tags and css

Comment: Why would you want to make a table and then read it back and process it? Why not just count the number of ones when you are creating the table in the first place?

Comment: Jose now actual code is added

Comment: thanks Jose post it as answer i will give you a positive vote

Comment: Isn't `$total` working? What error do you get?

Answer (score 0):

I really couldn't run your code (gives me so many errors), but do this anyway : define a counter `$total=0;` before `if(isset($_POST['submit']))`, declare it `global $total;` below the line `function Count($x,$y)`, increase it `$total++;` below the line `echo "One" ;`, and replace `echo count($value == 1);` by `echo $total;`, like this :

```
            <table width="600" border="1" align="center" cellspacing="5" bgcolor="#F0F0F0">
        <tr>
        <th>Number</th>
        <th>Value</th>
        <th>Find 1's</th>
        </tr> 
        <?php
        $total = 0; // <==========================================
        if(isset($_POST['submit']))
        {
        $x = $_POST['firstint'];
        $y = $_POST['secondint'];

        Count($x,$y);
        }

        function Count($x,$y)
        { global $total; // <==========================================
        for($i=$x; $i<=$y; $i++)
        {
        $value = $i/strlen($i);

        ?> 
        <tr>
        <td width="68" align="center"><?php echo $i; ?></td>
        <td width="68" align="center"><?php echo $value; ?></td>
        <td width="68" align="center">
        <?php 
        if($value == 1){ 
        echo "One" ; 
        $total++; // <==========================================
        }else{ 
        echo "Zero"; 
        } ?>
        </td></tr>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
        <tr>
        <td colspan="2" align="center"></td>
        <td align="left"><b>Total Count:</b></td>
        <td align="left"><b>
        <?php
        echo $total; // <==========================================
        ?>
        </b></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
        }
        ?>  
        </table>
```